# programmatically add a bunch of custom view from XIB to UIStackView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, uistackview

I have a TagDisplayCell.xib with the associate TagDisplayCell.m. In the `.m` file i load the view like so.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder: aDecoder];
    if(self){
        //load the interface file from .xib
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TagDisplayCell" owner:self options:nil];

        //add as subview
        [self addSubview:self.view];

        self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [self addConstraint:[self pin:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop]];
        [self addConstraint:[self pin:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft]];
        [self addConstraint:[self pin:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom]];
        [self addConstraint:[self pin:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight]];
    }

    return self;
}
```

In my view controller there is a vertical `UiStackView` (so that the contents are stacked in rows). I want to add several instances of the `TagDisplayCell` to this UiStackView. Here is what i am doing.

```
//create all the views 
for(int i=0; i<[commentsAndTagsArray count]; i++)
{
    NSObject *obj =commentsAndTagsArray[i];
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[Tag class]])
    {
        Tag *tempTag = ((Tag*) obj);
        TagDisplayCell *tempTagCell = [[TagDisplayCell alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [uiStackView addSubview:tempTagCell];
    }
}
```

When i run this nothing displays on the screen. What am i missing here?

**Update: Here is my TagDisplayCell.xib"**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you call `initWithFrame:` on a View subclass, it is not loaded from a XIB.

Perform loading of the view it in the same way like you did in your first code snippet:

```
TagDisplayCell *tempTagCell = (TagDisplayCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TagDisplay" owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
```

Comment: I am getting a crash with this line. I don't think i have the casting correct. I have updated my question with an image of the TagDisplayCell.xib

Comment: Yes, looks like you have a top level object a UIView, not TagDisplayCell. Is there a specific importance to have explicitly TagDisplayCell preferred to UIView?

Comment: The TagDisplayCell.xib has the the `Files Owner` set to TagDisplayCell. The TagDisplayCell.m has a few methods to do color changing and such. I think i don't understand. Doesn't attaching the files owner connect the class and the XIB?

Comment: You are doing wrong, because your Cell is a view and typically the view is a top-level object in a XIB. So you can change the class of a top-level object to your TagDisplayCell class.